Error handling and threading.Thread() issues
I am newer to Python, and I originally had error handling working as I liked. I wanted to add a progress bar using PySimpleGUI and after some research discovered that I needed to use threading. Once I implemented threading, the error handling no longer works as I'd like, and I cannot seem to figure out how to fix it. I will provide the code before the progress bar and after, but the after code does not have any error handling.
Old Code
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import functions_new as fn
import sys
import os

sg.theme("Default1")
sg.set_options(font=("Segoe UI Variable", 10))

input1 = sg.Input()
archive_choose = sg.FolderBrowse("Select Source Directory",
                                 key="source",
                                 pad=(5, 5))

input2 = sg.Input()
BOM_choose = sg.FileBrowse("Select BOM",
                           key="excel",
                           pad=(5, 5))

input3 = sg.Input()
save_dir = sg.FolderBrowse("Select Save Location",
                           key="save",
                           pad=(5, 5))

exec_button = sg.Button("Execute",
                        pad=(5, 5),
                        button_color=('White', 'NavyBlue'))



window = sg.Window(title="Step Name Replace",
                   layout=[[input1, archive_choose],
                           [input2, BOM_choose],
                           [input3, save_dir],
                           [exec_button]])

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
        break

    if event == "Execute":

        # calls func to search directory and store stepfiles in list
        filepaths = fn.stpFinder(values["source"])
        filepaths = [item.replace("\\", "/") for item in filepaths]

        try:
            print(f"Source Directory: {values['source']}")
            print(f"Source Directory: {values['excel']}")
            print(f"Source Directory: {values['save']}")

            # calls func to search directory and store stepfiles in list
            filepaths = fn.stpFinder(values["source"])
            filepaths = [item.replace("\\", "/") for item in filepaths]
            print(f"Found {len(filepaths)} .stp files")

            #gets df from excel
            df = fn.extractMREBOM(values["excel"])

            #runs name replace function
            for filepath in filepaths:
                new_name = os.path.join(values["save"], os.path.basename(filepath).replace(".stp", "_rename.stp"))

                print(f"Processing file: {filepath} -> {new_name}")
                fn.stepNameReplace(filepath, df, new_name)

            sg.popup("Process completed successfully!",
                     font=("Segoe UI Variable", 10))

        except PermissionError:
            sg.popup("Ensure that BOM and folder locations are closed before executing\n\n"
                     "Click OK to terminate",
                     font=("Segoe UI Variable", 10))
            sys.exit()

        except Exception as e:
            sg.popup(f"An error occurred: {e}",
                     font=("Segoe UI Variable", 10))

window.close()

New Code
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import functions_new as fn
import sys
import os
import threading


def execute_func(window, values):
    # Create new directory within source directory
    output_dir = os.path.join(values["source"], "SNR_Output")
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

    # Calls func to search directory and store stepfiles in list
    files = fn.stpFinder(values["source"])
    files = [item.replace("\\", "/") for item in files]
    print(f"Found {len(files)} .stp files")

    # Extracts df from excel
    df = fn.extractMREBOM(values["excel"])

    total_files = len(files)

    for index, file in enumerate(files):

        # Creates name for output step file
        new_name = os.path.join(output_dir, os.path.basename(file))

        # "Update" assigned to be called by elif to update status bar through each iteration
        window.write_event_value("Update", (index + 1, total_files))

        # Processes the file
        print(f"Processing file: {file}")
        fn.stepNameReplace(file, df, new_name)

    # Once loop completes, "Done" value assigned to be called by elif
    window.write_event_value("Done", None)

sg.theme("Default1")
sg.set_options(font=("Segoe UI Variable", 10))

layout = [
    [sg.Input(), sg.FolderBrowse("Select Source Directory", key="source", pad=(5, 5))],
    [sg.Input(), sg.FileBrowse("Select BOM", key="excel", pad=(5, 5))],
    [sg.Button("Execute", button_color=("White", "Grey")),
     sg.ProgressBar(100, orientation='h', size=(20, 20), key='progressbar', bar_color=("Salmon", "LightGrey")),
     sg.Text("", key="info")]
]

window = sg.Window(title="Step Name Replace (SNR)", layout=layout)


while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=100)

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == "Execute":
        print(f"Source Directory: {values['source']}")
        print(f"Source Directory: {values['excel']}")

        threading.Thread(target=execute_func, args=(window, values), daemon=True).start()

    elif event == "Update":
        current_file, total_files = values[event]
        window["progressbar"].update(current_file * 100 / total_files)
        window["info"].update(f"Working file {current_file} of {total_files}.")

    elif event == "Done":
        sg.popup("Process completed successfully!",
                 font=("Segoe UI Variable", 10))
        sys.exit()

window.close()

functions_new.py
from pandas import read_excel
import os
import sys
import PySimpleGUI as sg


# searches selected directory and extracts stepfiles into list
def stpFinder(source_dir):
    stp_files = []
    extensions = (".stp", ".step", ".STP", ".STEP")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(extensions):
                stp_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
    return stp_files


# Reads BOM excel and returns dataframe
def extractMREBOM(path):
    df = read_excel(path, sheet_name="BOM", dtype="str")

    des_count = df["DESCRIPTION"].count()
    num_count = df["DOC NUMBER"].count()
    type_count = df["DOC TYPE"].count()
    part_count = df["DOC PART"].count()

    # Checks if BOM is formatted correctly before returning df
    if des_count == num_count and type_count == part_count:
        return df

    else:
        sg.popup("BOM formatted incorrectly (Inconsistent number of rows)\n \n"
                 "Click OK to Terminate",
                 font=("Segoe UI Variable", 10))
        sys.exit()


# Uses returned dataframe to replace string names with BOM Description, then rename
def stepNameReplace(filepath_arg, df_arg, newName):

    output = open(newName, 'w+')
    file = open(filepath_arg, 'rb')

    for row in file:
        tmp_str = row.decode("utf-8").replace("\r\n", "\r")

        # Perform all replacements for the current line
        for i in range(len(df_arg["DESCRIPTION"])):
            tmp_str = tmp_str.replace(
                f"{df_arg['DOC NUMBER'][i]}_{df_arg['DOC TYPE'][i].upper()}_{df_arg['DOC PART'][i]}",
                df_arg['DESCRIPTION'][i])  # case Upper

            tmp_str = tmp_str.replace(
                f"{df_arg['DOC NUMBER'][i]}_{df_arg['DOC TYPE'][i].lower()}_{df_arg['DOC PART'][i]}",
                df_arg['DESCRIPTION'][i])  # case Lower

        # After all replacements, write the modified line to the output file
        output.write(tmp_str)
    output.close()
    return


And what's wrong with try ... except inside execute_func?

You cannot call sg.popup or most of GUI calls in extractMREBOM when threading, try to send a signal by window.write_event_value to your event loop to call popup, then close your window in your event loop. Another one issue is the file opened in stepNameReplace not closed.

@StasSimonov, when I do this, should it be a signal via window.write_event_value to a loop or can I call a popup within the function?

@DominickCole I strongly suggest you don't call any GUI functions inside a non-GUI thread execute_func. Instead, send a signal (event) to main (GUI) thread.

@JasonYang, thank you for pointing out the file close issue. Since extractMREBOM is inside the functions_new.py and not the gui.py file, how would I call window.write_event_value if window is undefined in functions_new.py?

@StasSimonov, would you suggest I keep using if elif or would match case be a better use for this? I don't want the code to run if an error occurs, but since if event "Execute" is still true. the code will be executed partially before the error occurs

You can return special value, like None, for function extractMREBOM when else, then check the value returned in execute_func to call window.write_event_value or not.

@DominickCole I think, the possible events should be Update, Done and Error.

@JasonYang, I'm not sure I follow, would you mind providing an example?

@StasSimonov so get rid of the Execute event? How will the program start when the execute button is pressed?

@DominickCole  Yes, and also the GUI event Execute is required.

@StasSimonov do you think async would be useful in this case?

@DominickCole I know that asyncio is an alternative of threading. But I prefer the threading as a common conception of many languages.

You cannot call sg.popup or most of GUI calls in extractMREBOM when threading, try to send a signal by window.write_event_value to your event loop to call sg.popup, then close your window in your event loop. Another one issue is the file opened in stepNameReplace not closed.
A simple example here for your reference
import threading
from time import sleep
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def execute_func(window):
    global stop
    total = 100
    for i in range(total):
        if stop:
            break
        sleep(0.1)
        value = check(i+1)
        if value is None:
            window.write_event_value("POPUP", i+1)
        elif value:
            window.write_event_value("Update", (i+1, total))
        else:
            window.write_event_value("Pass", i+1)
    window.write_event_value("Done", None)

def check(count):
    if count == 50:
        return None
    if count % 7:
        return True
    else:
        return False

sg.theme("DarkBlue")
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 16))

layout = [
    [sg.Multiline("", size=(40, 10), key="PASS")],
    [sg.ProgressBar(100, orientation='h', size=(20, 20), expand_x=True, expand_y=True, key='progressbar'),
     sg.Button("Execute")],
]
window = sg.Window("Demo", layout)
running, stop = False, True

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        stop = True
        sleep(1)
        break

    elif event == "Execute" and not running:
        running, stop = True, False
        threading.Thread(target=execute_func, args=(window,), daemon=True).start()

    elif event == "Update":
        count, total = values[event]
        window["progressbar"].update(current_count=count)

    elif event == "Pass":
        count = values[event]
        window["PASS"].update(f"Number {count} passed !!!\n", append=True, autoscroll=True)

    elif event == "POPUP":
        sg.popup("Pause here for count to 50, threading still running !", title="Message")

    elif event == "Done":
        running = False
        window["PASS"].update(f"~~~ All Done ~~~", append=True, autoscroll=True)

window.close()



Not critical, but did want to point out that PySimpleGUI added a simplified threading interface that includes ability to generate an event when the thread exits.  This is an example from a Demo Program that uses threading with progress bars.  I find the lambda easier to understand as it looks exactly like the call that will be made to start the thread (the args are not a separate parm)...  window.start_thread(lambda: the_thread(window), (THREAD_KEY, DL_THREAD_EXITNG))
`
